# Javascript/JQuery Check what part of website is in view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if it is possible to check with Javascript or JQuery what part of my `$(window)` is currently in the view for an user. I would like to do this to be able to determine if another application is completely overlapping the website or not.

I have already taken a look at the old `focus()` and `blur()`, however they do not completely suit my needs (could still be used in combination with other answers though).

I've also taken a look at the newer Visiblity API, however that does not detect if the window is completely visible or not. If it's being partly overlapped, then it returns `visible`, which is correct. However if it's fully overlapped, then it also returns `visible`, which is then not correct.

Comment: something like this perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: @Robb Sadly not, that answer is relative to the `$(window)` variable. I want to check if the browser window is visible in the `viewport` (PC's screen).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check if the browser is active or not? For example, overlapped by MS Excel? Or what do you mean by "partially overlapped"?

Comment: @b__ Correct, that's what I want to check.